# Access 2016 DLOOKUP

Tags: ms-access-2016

How do you look up a table field to be used in a form with DLOOKUP? The following is what I've been using, but keep getting #TYPE! error.

```
=DLookUp("[ProductName]","[TblProduct]","[TblProduct].[ProductCode] =" & Str([ProductCode_Text].[Text])
```

Comment: You may need the _Value_ property: `=DLookUp("[ProductName]","[TblProduct]","[ProductCode] = '" & Me![ProductCode_Text].Value & "'")`.

Answer (score 0):

Your product code needs to be enclosed in single quotes:

```
=DLookUp("[ProductName]","[TblProduct]","[TblProduct].[ProductCode] = '" & Str([ProductCode_Text].[Text] & "'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much. I have modified the code and it work but this is the most efficient way?

```
Private Sub Location_AfterUpdate()
Dim filteritem As String
DoCmd.OpenTable "item_Detail"
Me.Units_in_UOM.Visible = True

filteritem = "[ItemId]=" & "'" & Me.Item & "'"
MsgBox (filteritem) ' just for testing need to delete
Me.Units_in_UOM = DLookup("[QPC]", "[Item_Detail]", filteritem)
'Me.Units_in_UOM = DLookup("[QPC]", "[Item_Detail]", "[ItemId]=" & 'filteritem)

End Sub
```